# ParameterMissing param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller, parameter-passing

i have the following situation:
I have a controller for admins , that i use to manage the users (model generated by Devise).

So, i use the actions of another controller to manage the resources "users".

Here my files:

admins_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to admins_index_path, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:id)
  end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit user</h1>

<%= form_for @user, :as => :patch, :url => admins_update_path(id: @user) do |f| %>

  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this line_item from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
    </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :admin %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :admin %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that when i submit the edit , rails gives me an error:

[image]

Can you help me? i really don t knok how to fix
thank you

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your view to drop the `:as` option, that will fix the params requirement error:

```
= form_for @user, :url => admins_update_path(id: @user) do |f|
```

The `:as` tells `form_for` to use a different key name than the default class-name based one that you're using in your `params.require` call.

You should also remove your `f.text_field :id` - you don't want someone editing that.

Then your `permit(...)` block will need to include anything else in that form that you want to allow mass-assignment for, most likely you'll want: `permit(:email, :admin)`

Comment: i can't change my form_to cause rails will use the UserController that doesn't exist. I used another controller, the AdminController, to manage users. If i use form_for @user do |f| rails will search user_controller.

Comment: Ok, so at least drop the `:as` option, that specifically tells `form_for` to put the params in a different key than the default class-name based key.

Comment: hi man, now the error disappears but the update (even if all is passed) doesn't work. Do you have any idea? here the image in the main post

Comment: ah, i edit params.require(:user).permit(:id) in params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email). But still doesn t work

Comment: Sorry, i was really tired and i didn't notice my error. I put params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email) but i passed :admin to upload. i fixed with params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email,:admin) and everythings works. Thx @smathy . If you want , can you explain me the fact about :as option ? thank you so much man

Comment: As I mentioned in my original answer, I would remove `:id` and add both `:email` and `:name`